# JavaScript - What Level of Code Optimization can one expect?

Tags: javascript, optimization, performance

So, I am fairly new to JavaScript coding, though not new to coding in general. When writing source code I generally have in mind the environment my code will run in (e.g. a virtual machine of some sort) - and with it the *level of code optimization one can expect*. (1)

In Java for example, I might write something like this,

```
Foo foo = FooFactory.getFoo(Bar.someStaticStuff("qux","gak",42);
blub.doSomethingImportantWithAFooObject(foo);
```

even if the `foo` object only used at this very location (thus introducing an needless variable declaration). Firstly it is my opinion that the code above is way better readable than the inlined version

```
blub.doSomethingImportantWithAFooObject(FooFactory.getFoo(Bar.someStaticStuff("qux","gak",42));
```

and secondly I know that Java compiler code optimization will take care of this anyway, i.e. the actual Java VM code will end up being inlined - so performance wise, there is no diffence between the two. (2)

Now to my actual **Question**:
*What Level of Code Optimization can I expect in JavaScript in general?*

I assume this depends on the JavaScript engine - but as my code will end up running in many different browsers lets just assume the worst and look at the worst case. Can I expect a moderate level of code optimization? What are some cases I still have to worry about?

---

(1) I do realize that finding good/the best algorithms and writing well organized code is more important and has a bigger impact on performance than a bit of code optimization. But that would be a different question.

(2) Now, I realize that the actual difference were there no optimization is small. But that is beside the point. There are easily features which are optimized quite efficiently, I was just kind of too lazy to write one down. Just imagine the above snippet inside a `for` loop which is called 100'000 times.

Comment: I realize it's just an example, but it indicates you have a questionable approach to optimization, so I'll nitpick anyway. Even with no optimization at all, the difference between your snippets is an extra K byte stack slot (likely 4 <= k <= 12; the stack may be the "CPU stack" or just an array), an extra store to and load from that slot, plus possibly interpretation overhead for those two instructions. Even the function call overhead may easily be larger.

Comment: @delnan I don't really get what your aiming at... The two code snippets will (almost certainly) end up as the exact same Java bytecode as the compiler _will_ do optimization no matter what. So apart from the overhead during compilation (which you don't care about in Java) the snippets have zero performance difference.

Comment: I guess the point is that optimization in that snippet is not very meaningful. Without inlining there shouldn't be any performance issues, either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't expect much on the optimization, there won't be

- the tail-recursive optimization,
- loop unfolding,
- inline function
- *etc*

As javascript on client is not designed to do heavy CPU work, the optimization won't make a huge difference.

There are some guidelines for writing hi-performance javascript code, most are minor and technics, like:

- Not use certain functions like `eval()`, `arguments.callee` and etc, which will prevent the js engine from generating hi-performance code.
- Use native features over hand writing ones, like don't write your own containers, json parser etc.
- Use local variable instead of global ones.
- Never use for-each loop for array.
- Use `parseInt()` rather than `Math.floor`.
- AND stay away from jQuery.

All these technics are more like experience things, and may have some reasonable explanations behind. So you will have to spend some time search around or try [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com) to help you decide which approach is better.

When you release the code, use [closure compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/) to take care of dead-branch and unnecessary-variable things, which will not boost up your performance a lot, but will make your code smaller.

Generally speaking, the final performance is highly depending on how well your code organized, how carefully your algorithm designed rather than how the optimizer performed.

---

Take your example above (by assuming `FooFactory.getFoo()` and `Bar.someStaticStuff("qux","gak",42)` is always returning the same result, and `Bar`, `FooFactory` are stateless, that `someStaticStuff()` and `getFoo()` won't change anything.)

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
  blub.doSomethingImportantWithAFooObject(
      FooFactory.getFoo(Bar.someStaticStuff("qux","gak",42));
```

Even the g++ with -O3 flag can't make that code faster, for compiler can't tell if `Bar` and `FooFactory` are stateless or not. So these kind of code should be avoided in any language.

Comment: I'm not really concerned with optimizing the above snippet, its purpose was just to demonstrate how I might deliberately avoid inlining due to readability purposes because I know that after code optimization there will be no difference.

Comment: You didn't get my point. Javascript on client is *not* for heavy CPU work, but more like event-driving. Make 10k function calls in 50ms won't make the user experience any performance loss compare to inline version's 45ms. Cause doing these kind of optimization in js won't reduce the a great number of cpu ops like in C/C++, always remember this is a script language. So just write your code as long as it's maintainable, and ignore these kind of optimization and focus on things that really matters like algorithm, APIs you use, etc.

Comment: +1 for stay away from jQuery! (not to mention it and its plugins make debugging a nightmare).

Comment: It's refreshing to see someone NOT say "throw jQuery at it!".  :)

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the level of optimization is different from JS VM to VM. But! there is a way of working around that. There are several tools that will optimize/minimize your code for you. One of the most popular ones is by Google. It's called the Closure-Compiler. You can try out the [web-version](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) and there is a cmd-line version for build-script etc. Besides that there is not much I would try about optimization, because after all Javascript is sort of fast enough.

Answer (score 1):

In general, I would posit that unless you're playing really dirty with your code (leaving all your vars at global scope, creating a lot of DOM objects, making expensive AJAX calls to non-optimal datasources, etc.), the real trick with optimizing performance will be in managing all the other things you're loading in at run-time.

Loading dozens on dozens of images, or animating huge background images, and pulling in large numbers of scripts and css files can all have much greater impact on performance than even moderately-complex Javascript that is written well.

That said, a quick Google search turns up several sources on Javascript performance optimization:
http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/JavaScript_Performance_Best_Practices

http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/02/03/speed-up-your-javascript-part-4/

http://mir.aculo.us/2010/08/17/when-does-javascript-trigger-reflows-and-rendering/

As two of those links point out, the most expensive operations in a browser are reflows (where the browser has to redraw the interface due to DOM manipulation), so that's where you're going to want to be the most cautious in terms of performance. Some of that can be alleviated by being smart about what you're modifying on the fly (for example, it's less expensive to apply a class than modify inline styles ad hoc,) so separating your concerns (style from data) will be really important.

Making only the modifications you *have* to, in order to get the job done, (ie. rather than doing the "HULK SMASH (DOM)!" method of replacing entire chunks of pages with AJAX calls to screen-scraping remote sources, instead calling for JSON data to update only the minimum number of elements needed) and other common-sense approaches will get you a lot farther than hours of minor tweaking of a for-loop (though, again, common sense will get you pretty far, there, too).

Good luck!